# Subscript out of range error

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub sendemail(esubj)

    ROW_BEGIN = 1
    ROW_END = 72

    Sheets("Input").Select
    Range("A" & ROW_BEGIN & ":S" & ROW_END).Select
    Range("A" & ROW_BEGIN).Select

    fileL = "\\fire\school\FINANCE\Report\FY10\Key Indicator\"
    fileL = fileL & (Left(Range("I7"), 3)) & Right(Year(Date), 2)
    fileL = fileL & "\Key Report - " & myfdate & ".xls"
```

I have a workbook with a spreadsheet tab named Input. When I try to run it, I get the Subscript out of range message. Why cant it pull from the Input spreadsheet??

Answer (score 0):

Why are you performing all the `Select`s?

What line does the code fail at?